# How can I use html agility to grab everything between <b> and <br>

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I poorly asked about this same project last week and didn't receive any suggestions. I will try to be more clear.  I am trying to work with data from the website [www.gtin13.com](http://gtin13.com). For example if you enter peanut butter into the search, I am trying to grab the **description:**Nabisco Nutter Butter Sandwich Cookies Chocolate Peanut Butter 4 Ct The **Size***:Size: 12 oz The **GTIN:** 0044000003562  ***ean**:**00-44000-00356-2 **upc:** 044000003562 and **upca:** 04400000356. I have tried using nodeCollection with SelectNodes`("<b>")` and all I get are errors.  Is it even possible using html agility to grab the data between the `<b> <br>` as well and then parse between the /s? With my lack of experience I just can't make any headway on this. It doesn't appear that the returned page has what I would consider true nodes. If html agility can't do this can anyone suggest a better approach? Eventually I would like to send each piece of the data to a sql table. I hope I have presented in a way that makes better sense.

The page returns the information in this source format:

```
<b><a href="/product/nabisco+nutter+butter+sandwich+cookies+chocolate+peanut+butter+4+ct/">Nabisco Nutter Butter Sandwich Cookies Chocolate Peanut Butter 4 Ct</a></b><br />

Size: 12 oz<br />

GTIN/EAN-13: 0044000003562 / 00-44000-00356-2<br />

UPC-A: 044000003562 / 04400000356<br />



Tags:

<a href="/tag/chocolate/">Chocolate</a>, 

<a href="/tag/cookies/">Cookies</a>, 
 ..<br />

<br >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that easy because the original document is quite unstructured (not using a hierarchical layout, but a flat one), but here is how you can extract the main text fields with the Html Agility Pack:

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load("yourDoc.Htm");

        // Get A nodes that have an HREF attribute
        foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//b/a[@href]"))
        {
            // This will contain anchor's displayed text
            string title = node.InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine("title=" + title);

            // Get the 1st BR, and then it's next sibling of TEXT type.
            HtmlNode sizeNode = node.SelectSingleNode("../following-sibling::br[1]/following-sibling::text()");
            Console.WriteLine(" size=" + sizeNode.InnerText.Trim());

            // Get the 3nd BR, and then it's next sibling of TEXT type.
            HtmlNode eanNode = node.SelectSingleNode("../following-sibling::br[2]/following-sibling::text()");
            Console.WriteLine(" ean=" + eanNode.InnerText.Trim());

            // Get the 3rd BR, and then it's next sibling of TEXT type.
            HtmlNode upcNode = node.SelectSingleNode("../following-sibling::br[3]/following-sibling::text()");
            Console.WriteLine(" upc=" + upcNode.InnerText.Trim());
        }
```

This will display:

```
title=Peanut Delight Peanut Butter & Grape Jelly
 size=Size: 18 oz
 ean=GTIN/EAN-13: 0041498143909 / 00-41498-14390-9
 upc=UPC-A: 041498143909 / 04149814390
title=Nabisco Nutter Butter Sandwich Cookie Bites Peanut Butter
 size=Size: 10 oz
 ean=GTIN/EAN-13: 0044000046118 / 00-44000-04611-8
 upc=UPC-A: 044000046118 / 04400004611
title=Nabisco Nutter Butter Sandwich Cookies Chocolate Peanut Butter 4 Ct
 size=Size: 12 oz
 ean=GTIN/EAN-13: 0044000003562 / 00-44000-00356-2
 upc=UPC-A: 044000003562 / 04400000356
```

etc...

NOTE: It's not 100% finished, as you'll have to parse the size, ean and upc variable using standard string manipulation (IndexOf, Substring, etc...) or Regex but the Html side of things is done.

Comment: @Simon wow, I was ready to give up on this and admit I a not smart enough to figure it out.  I guess I still have to admit I wasn't smart enough to figure it out since you did it.  I really appreciate it! I will study it ans see what I can learn from it.

Comment: @Simon While working with the data, I now notice they have not included "Size" in each dataset.  How might I add "Size " " " to the sets that don't have size included. Without it, it throws off the sequence for adding to a database. Thanks

Comment: @JRB - it's easier to do this in C# procedural code. For example, "if upc is null or empty then ean=upc, upc=size, size=''"

Comment: @Simon, If this is what your saying how do I solve the cant convert string to htmlagilitypack.htmlnode:                 HtmlNode upcNode = node.SelectSingleNode("../following-sibling::br[3]/following-sibling::text()");            
           if(upcNode=" ")
           {
               upcNode = eanNode;
           }
           else
           {

            Regex r1 = new Regex("[0-9]{12}");

Comment: @Simon sorry that didn't format well in that comment let me know if I should post a whole new question.

Comment: @JRB - something like that yes, but it's quite out of Html Agility Pack hands, it's pure C# logic.

Comment: @Simon Simon thank you for your ideas, I was able to come up with a solution. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Using HTQL, the query to extract the whole table from the page is:

```
<div (CLASS='BGC')>1.<div (CLASS='CON')>1.<div (CLASS='SC')>1.<div (ID='post-20')>1.<div (CLASS='PostContent')>1.<b sep>2-0 {
  title=<a>1:tx; 
  size=/'Size:'~'<br />'/;
  gtin=/'GTIN/EAN-13:'~'<br />'/;
  upc=/'UPC-A:'~'<br />'/;
  tags=/'Tags:'~'<br />'/;
}
```

If you only need to send the results to sql database, then I sugguest you use IRobotSoft web scraper.

Comment: seagulf thank you for your suggestion, I am not familiar with HTQL I will read up on it. This can be used in a c# application?

Answer (score 0):

String Split takes strings in addition to characters:

```
String[] Sections = HTML.Split(new string[] {"<b>", "<br />"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Regex for that, since HtmlAgilityPack is probably going to want to have properly formed html tags, as in a `<b>` without a **`</b>`** is an improper tag pair, that is why you are getting errors.  `<br >` and `<br />` are not the end tag to the starting `<b>` (bold) tag.

If you are not the generator of the HTML, then like I said, I'd suggest Regex, and tell it you want everything between the `<b>` and the `<br >` tags.  But since you have a couple different break tags, you might have problems with that too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing SelectNodes uses xpath?  So you should be doing something like.. SelectNotes("//b" ) to get all the b nodes.

Simple examples of xpath are here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

You could select the links and only look at ones that have href starting with 'product' to group nodes?